# How can I remove empty array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this code in php.

```
 public function display_children($parent,$level){
 try {
          $cmd = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT mem,pid from mytree where pid = ?');

          $cmd->execute(array($parent));



          while ( $row =  $cmd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


               $rec[] = [['v' => $row['mem'], 'f' => $row['mem']], (string)$row['pid'], $row['mem']];


              $this->display_children($row['mem'], $level + 1);

          }

               echo json_encode(rec);
      }
      catch(PDOException $ex){
          return $ex->getMessage();
      }

  }
```

And this is the result in my ajax

```
[][][[{"v":"9","f":"9"},"7","9"],[{"v":"10","f":"10"},"7","10"]][][[{"v":"7","f":"7"},"5","7"],[{"v":"8","f":"8"},"5","8"]]
```

I want to remove those empty array to be like this.is it possible ?

```
[[{"v":"9","f":"9"},"7","9"],[{"v":"10","f":"10"},"7","10"],[{"v":"7","f":"7"},"5","7"],[{"v":"8","f":"8"},"5","8"]]
```

I tried to use this to remove the empty array but it failed to remove.

```
 $rec = array_filter($rec);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would create those empty elements at the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public function display_children($parent,$level, $rec = array()){
    try {
        $cmd = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT mem,pid from mytree where pid = ?');

        $cmd->execute(array($parent));

        while ( $row =  $cmd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $rec[] = [['v' => $row['mem'], 'f' => $row['mem']], (string)$row['pid'], $row['mem']];

            $rec = $this->display_children($row['mem'], $level + 1, $rec);
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        //return $ex->getMessage();
        return $rec;
    }

    return $rec;
}
```

First call:

```
echo json_encode(display_children(5, 0));
```

Comment: this cannot work, cause as soon as the while loop passes only once $exists is true

Comment: 'echo json_encode' starts after the loop in topic. so it will display empty array in all cases. so we need to skip 'echo json_encode' if loop body is skipped.

Comment: almost got it [[{"v":"9","f":"9"},"7","9"],[{"v":"10","f":"10"},"7","10"]][[{"v":"7","f":"7"},"5","7"],[{"v":"8","f":"8"},"5","8"]] but there is ][ near 10,it should like this [[{"v":"9","f":"9"},"7","9"],[{"v":"10","f":"10"},"7","10"],[{"v":"7","f":"7"},"5","7"],[{"v":"8","f":"8"},"5","8"]]

Comment: yes, but if i understand the question correctly the filds form the db can be empty and this results in empty array parts. You only checking if is ther any result from the db. And for this you can simply use if(!empty($rec)) instead of using a variable

Comment: I have added "if ($level > 1) echo ',';" to the answer if you use $level = 0 in first call. Please check.

Comment: @ashTon How do you run display_children firstly? display_children(...,**0**)? or display_children(...,**1**)?

Comment: @AlexYashin, display_children(5,0)

Comment: @ashTon, I have corrected code. So we need to capture old output to know when out delimiter ','. Please note: 'echo' should be run after output string construction.

Comment: @AlexYashin, here is the output [[{"v":"9","f":"9"},"7","9"],[{"v":"10","f":"10"},"7","10"]],[[{"v":"7","f":"7"},"5","7"],[{"v":"8","f":"8"},"5","8"]]

Comment: @AlexYashin,but how can I remove the extra ][ near 10 so that it should like this.[[{"v":"9","f":"9"},"7","9"],[{"v":"10","f":"10"},"7","10"],[{"v":"7","f":"7"},"5","7"],[{"v":"8","f":"8"},"5","8"]]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66896/discussion-between-alex-yashin-and-ashton).

Answer (score 2):

you can use array_filter to do this.

```
function filter($var){
  return !empty($var);
}

$array1 = array("a"=>null, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);

$newarray = array_filter($array1, "filter"));
```

result: 
Array
(
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
)